# How to calculate the TAT (total air temperature) when a rocket is flying to space?

Tags: supersonic, temperature

I checked [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/84975/how-much-aerodynamic-heating-do-jetliners-endure) and I used the formula this answerer provided, but I couldn't get the data he/she presented in the graph. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: How can we address "did I do something wrong" when you don't show us *what you did*?  As they teach in 6th grade math, ***show your work***.

Answer (score 3):

Since you didn't show your calculation / results I can only assume what went wrong. Something easily missed is using the correct **units** for the calculation. The formula

$$ \frac{\text{TAT}}{\text{SAT}} = 1 + \frac{\gamma - 1}{2} M^2 = 1 + \frac{1}{5} M^2 $$

only works for TAT and SAT as **absolute temperatures**. You have to use Kelvin (or degrees Rankine), **not** degrees Celsius (or Fahrenheit), for the calculations.

For the plots shown in the answer, I did all the calculations in Kelvin and then converted the results to degrees Celsius. Try repeating your calculation in Kelvin and see if you get consistent results.

*Additional Note:* since you want to use this calculation for a rocket flying to space, note that the formula only really works when air can be approximated as an ideal gas. Additionally, $ \gamma = 7 / 5 $ only holds for diatomic gases. At some altitude, these assumptions are no longer useful approximations, so you cannot use this formula all the way to space.